# Excel VBA - Merge 2 Cell Formulas

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have 2 formulas in 2 different cells that i want to merge into 1. They look like:

```
ActiveCell.Formula = "=(" & Range(Cells(k1, 2), Cells(k1, 2)).Address(False, False) & "+" & Range(Cells(k1, 6), Cells(k1, 6)).Address(False, False) & ")"

ActiveCell.Formula = "=(" & Range(Cells(k4, 2), Cells(k4, 2)).Address(False, False) & "+" & Range(Cells(k4, 6), Cells(k4, 6)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Where k4/k1 are values from a For Loop. Is there any way for me to add these 2 cells but keep the formula?

So if the value in the first cell was =A1+A2 (5) and the second was =B1+B2 (15). Then the cell that i want the final value in would be =A1+A2+B1+B2 instead of just 20. This way if the values in A1/A2/B1/B2 were changed, it would recalculate the value.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Why not just add the second string to the end of the first?

Answer (score 1):

Something like below? What it does is:

1) Creates a container variable to collect all the formulae (`result`)

2) Loops through the range

3) Collects the cell formula (except the equals sign) (`func`)

4) Concatenates the cell formulae

5) Returns the result into a cell

Note though that for many (or long) formulae, this might break once they become too much for Excel.

```
Sub merge()

result = ""

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C2")

func = Right(cell.Formula, Len(cell.Formula) - 1)

result = result & "+" & func

Next cell

ActiveSheet.Range("C3").Formula = result

End Sub
```